# CMake Treat Warnings as Errors

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-warnings

How can I configure CMake to treat compiler warnings as errors during the build?

I am aware of the possibility to manually configure command line options for the compiler like `-Werror` through commands like `target_compile_options`, but I would prefer a portable solution that does not require fiddling with tool-dependent options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be configured in CMake version 3.24 and higher via the [`COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR) target property.

For example, to enable warnings as errors for the `my_app` target you could write:

```
set_property(TARGET my_app PROPERTY COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR ON)
```

You can also set a global default for all targets in your project via the [`CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR.html#variable:CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR) variable:

```
set(CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR ON)

add_executable(my_app1 [...])
add_executable(my_app2 [...])
add_executable(my_app3 [...])
```

If a user finds it annoying that this is set in the CMakeLists.txt file, they can still override it using the [`--compile-no-warning-as-error`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-compile-no-warning-as-error) configure option.

Comment: This would be a _significantly_ better answer if it discussed the pitfalls of forcing `-Werror` to be enabled, regardless of the consumer's toolchain and if it used `option()` to default it to `ON` rather than leaving it hard-coded.

Comment: @AlexReinking I agree with your point about the pitfalls, but I'm not sure if it really is an issue here. Since the option is set via a target property and those do not propagate to dependent targets, I don't see an issue where my decision to enforce `-Werror` for my own project could leak through to my customers.

Comment: Do you not expect any of your customers, either external or internal to your company, to build your code from source?

Comment: @AlexReinking That depends on the project. After thinking about it some more, I think I see your point now. In a scenario where you ship me a library in source and I intend to build it on a compiler that you never tested, `-Werror` can cause some pretty annoying issues for me, even if the code is fine in principle. I am still reluctant to caution against the use of `-Werror` in general, as there are plenty of projects out there where this is not an issue (e.g. because they only ship in binary form).

Comment: For those who are not fluent in CMake, `option(CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR "Compile warnings as errors" ON)` can replace `set(CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR ON)`, whilst giving the developer the option to turn off via `cmake ... -DCMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR=false` at the configure stage.

Answer (score 1):

Treating warnings as errors is a good practice for CI systems with a fixed and predictable toolchain, but it is **inappropriate** to force on all users. Many are likely using a different toolchain with different sets of warnings and sensitivities for those warnings. Enabling `-Werror` by default causes broken builds for your consumers and is a bad practice.

Notably, this exact issue was the source of one major debacle in the last year in the Linux kernel: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b339ec9c229aaf399296a120d7be0e34fbc355ca

It is also prohibited by the Gentoo packaging archives (important because it is a source-based distribution): https://devmanual.gentoo.org/ebuild-writing/common-mistakes/index.html

Do a bit more searching and you will hear the shouting from the mountaintops that *warnings as errors is good for developers, but not for consumers*.

The best way to do this, then, is to set the new (as of CMake 3.24) variable `CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR` set to `ON` *only* when you know it is safe to do so. That is to say, it should not be on by default (but if you *insist*, then there ***must*** be a way to disable it).

There are many good ways to set this up:

1. You could add it to the `cacheVariables` section of a [preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html)
2. You could `set` it to `ON` in a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html)
3. You can simply pass it at the command line when you want to toggle it on or off.

Speaking as someone who regularly uses top-of-tree compiler builds, where warnings break frequently, hard-coded warnings-as-errors is a blight. It forces me and countless other package maintainers, devops teams, and so on, to patch your build.

Comment: Too much of your opinion and too little of the actual answer. Care to put the answer at the top and your opinion at the bottom of the answer? For the future readers: this opinion is controversial at best. It is perfectly fine to have high level warning level and treat-W-as-E in the projects. It is a good practice despite what is written in this answer. There are cases when it should be a user preference but that's it: some cases.

Comment: @ixSci - this opinion is _**far**_ from controversial. My answer already refutes the rest of your comment.

Comment: @ixSci - flagged for CoC. Cite a source instead of ad-hom-ing me.

Comment: You can go as far back as FOSDEM 2010 when the Gentoo folks literally gave a talk about how to be a good upstream and keeping -Werror out of the defaults was one of their main points. This has been a recommended practice for at least a _decade_.

Comment: Gentoo is just one project. They have their policy and that's fine. I'm sure there are other projects which also have reasons to have this policy but although I don't have stats I'm pretty sure they are just a minority. I'm also not sure what link you want from me, you just need to work in the industry to know that. Although if you insist on having some authority, here, have a link to [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Windows_Code) and/or watch/attend videos from major C++ conferences, it is a rare (people usually know that) but recurring thing there.

Comment: @ixSci - I spoke at CppCon in 2020 so it's not like I'm unfamiliar with "videos from major C++ conferences". To which part of the Google style guide are you referring? The only mention of warnings as errors I could find is for MSVC specifically. Also, most of Google's major open source libraries disable -Werror by default, including GLog, GTest, and GMock. All use -Werror in CI.

Comment: I give you the specific link. Yes it is in a Windows part but the way it worded, it is implied to teach Windows programmer the "correct style" so I assume it goes w/o saying about non-MSVC toolsets. Otherwise that rule would make no sense. I also remember Chandler Carruth saying to use `werror` but I can't prove it because I won't go rewatch all his videos. Anyway, I made my point and I don't really want to persuade you of anything, especially when I find your arguments valid but your position of imposing some rules, which are valid in some projects, absolutely inappropriate.

Comment: This is an interesting challenge to my fairly strong (even religious) opinion that warnings as errors is good, thank you.  Mostly my career has been closed-shop, but I'm starting to think about developing libraries that can be used more widely. Couple of points: (1) is `option(CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR "Compile warnings as errors" ON)` sufficient to allay your concerns? (2) A little naïve, but not sure why `SYSTEM` includes don't solve your problems (now even supported on MSVC). Is this because you are actually building the dependent packages rather than taking them pre-installed?